# Keynote 6.6: How can I make an object wider by animation, but not higher

Tags: keynote, animation

I want to animate a block to be wider, but not higher.

from this:

```
____________________
|    Some Text      |
---------------------
```

to this:

```
______________________________________
|             Some Text               |
--------------------------------------
```

The scale animation seems to work only with locked ratio and can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Looks like it can't do it. Maybe overlaying a black bar (or whatever your background colour is) over the top and bottom of the shape would be good enough? This wouldn't actually scale the text but the background to the text would appear to just be resizing horizontally.

Comment: I thought on that, but the problem is that my shape has a border line. will try to do it somehow then.

Comment: Have you tried two objects and a Magic Move?

Answer (score 4):

One way to accomplish this is with the **Magic Move** animation.  However this will require an additional slide.  Duplicating the slides including their content will not give the appearance of a slide change, only items that are moved or changed will appear to animate, not the slide itself.  See animation below.

- Create your object on one slide.
- Duplicate the slide.
- Resize the object in the second slide to the desired width.
- Set animation on the first slide to **Magic Move**
- Change the animation duration and/or acceleration to the desired result.

#### Slide one:

[image: First slide demonstrating Magic Move]

#### Slide two:

[image: Second Slide]

#### Resulting animation:

[image: Animation]

Comment: Was this helpful?